# Access Denied with using JHipster Spring Config Server

Tags: spring, jwt, spring-cloud, jhipster

**Question on JWT token and the JHipster Spring Cloud Config Service**

The documentation (http://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) is little vague on how / what to copy for JWT tokens.

*It says:*

the JHipster Spring Config server makes sure that the config/JWT tokens are available and services authenticated. I have deployed the JHipster Config Server, Gaeway and one Microservice with an Entity.

When I try to call through the Gateway a backend microservice/with Entity (to create Author/Book) it tells me Access denied.

I believe once you register your microservice and gateway with the Config Server, the tokens are copied over to the Config Server and it should work without copying any tokens around.

*Any idea how this is supposed to work?.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should share the key by copying it into the registry's [environment repository](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_environment_repository) as `jhipster.security.authentication.jwt.secret` property in global `application-dev.yml` and `application-prod.yml`. Use different keys for prod and dev.

These shared yml files are the ones in your native environment repository (by default `jhipster-registry/central-config`) or git-based environment repository not in the `src/main/resources/config` folder of the registry itself.

```
jhipster:
    security:
        authentication:
            jwt:
                secret: "***********************"
```